# How can i get (function '(a b a a b c)) => ((a a a) (b b))?

Tags: recursion, common-lisp

I am studying common lisp tutorials but I am not familiar with it.

How can i get the following result?

```
(function '(a b a a b c)) => ((a a a) (b b))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy. You have `remove-if` and `remove-if-not`. They work like this:

```
(remove-if-not (lambda (x) (eq x 'a)) '(a b a a b c)) ; ==> (a a a)
(remove-if (lambda (x) (eq x 'a)) '(a b a a b c)) ; ==> (b b c)
```

Now if you have an argument and it's not `nil` you use the above to make the first element of the result and what list to pass to the recursion.

A typical recursive function:

```lisp
(defun group (list)
  (if (endp list)
      nil
      (cons <??> (group <??>))))
```

There are more efficient ways to do it and you might want to make your own functions instead of relying on `remove-if(-not)` as an exercise.